# How to write text input to new line in file?

Tags: php, newline, textinput

This is my code where I want input from text field on new line. For example, if the input text is first name and last name then I want last name on new line and I have only one text field. How can I do that ?

```
 if (isset($string) and (bool)preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $string) == TRUE) {
    //if yes, it is writing it into file
    $myfile = fopen("names.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $txt = $string;
    fwrite($myfile, $txt);

    fclose($myfile);
    }
    else {
        echo "Sorry, your name is not in correct format.";
    }
```

Comment: You can us `PHP_EOL` or `"\n"` but you have to do that to `$string` before writing it to the file. So show us how you create `$string`

Comment: $string = $_POST["names"]       this is how I created $string. This is just before above if statement

Comment: Then you are going to have to define the contents of `$_POST["names"]` and ...just for example .... replace the space between names with a newline. But to do that you have to be sure that there a) will actually be a space b) be sure that there will only be one space c) etc etc

Comment: OK. First and Last<input type="text" name="names"> this is only text input I am using. If I use two text inputs then PHP_EOL and "\n" works. But not with single text input

Comment: I was going to suggest you break the field into 2 seperate fields. So use that method

Comment: Ok.Thank you. But is it possible with one field ?

Comment: Anything is possible, but with one string there are just to many thing that can go wrong. You could do `$string = str_replace(' ', "\n", $string);`

Comment: But if someone has a name like `Billy Bob Thornton` it wont give you the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this [solution](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc1e910997e7af3b4f6e7a67a89793323ca7b28e) will be true

```
$names = [
    's34S$2 John',
    'John James Smith',
    'stack overflow',
    'John Smith',
    'John Johnson',
    'JohnWilliams',
    'Stack Best Overflow',
    'Smith'
];

$delimiter = '\n'; // "\n" for real use

foreach($names as $name){

    $newName = preg_replace(
        '/^([A-Z][a-z]+([\ ][A-Z][a-z]+)*)([\ ][A-Z][a-z]+)+$/',
        "$1$delimiter$3",
        $name
    );

    if ( $newName != $name ){
        echo "'$name' => '$newName'\n";
        // file_put_contents("names.txt", $newName); for real use
    } else {
        echo "'$name' =>  Sorry, your name is not in correct format.\n";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
's34S$2 John' =>  Sorry, your name is not in correct format.
'John James Smith' => 'John James\n Smith'
'stack overflow' =>  Sorry, your name is not in correct format.
'John Smith' => 'John\n Smith'
'John Johnson' => 'John\n Johnson'
'JohnWilliams' =>  Sorry, your name is not in correct format.
'Stack Best Overflow' => 'Stack Best\n Overflow'
'Smith' =>  Sorry, your name is not in correct format.
```